# Perl syntax in relation to references

Tags: perl

Consider x is an array reference.

I know that `[]` gives an anonymous array reference and `{}` gives an anonymous hash reference. Now what does `@{$x}` mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This means *dereference* an *array ref*.

You will see the content of the referenced array.

Note that you could use the simple

```
@$x
```

in your case.

The `{ }` characters are needed when you have multiple levels in your *data structure* like in this example :

```
@{ $foo->{first_level}->{second_level} }
```

or

```
@{ $foo->[$first_level]->[$second_level] }
```

This works too with others [sigils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29) :

```
%{ } # HASH
$    # SCALAR
```

See [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Answer (score 8):

It's a dereference. `@{ $ref }` is to references as `@array` is to arrays, meaning you'd use `@{ $ref }` wherever you'd use `@array`.

```
>perl -E"@array = qw( a b c ); say $_ for @array;"
a
b
c

>perl -E"$ref = [qw( a b c )]; say $_ for @{ $ref };"
a
b
c
```

The curlies can be omitted when unambiguous.

```
>perl -E"$ref = [qw( a b c )]; say $_ for @$ref;"
a
b
c
```

- [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)
- [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

Comment: +1 for perlreftut! The best document for learning to create and use references out there!

Answer (score 4):

if `$x` is a reference to an array, as in

```
@a = (1,2,3);
$x = \@a
```

then with `@$x` or `@{$x}`, you get back `@a`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on context and what follows.  In scalar context:

```
$y = @{$x};
```

it will return a count of elements in the array to which `$x` is a reference.

In list context:

```
@y = @{$x};
```

it will return the elements of the array.

If followed by `[LIST]`:

```
@{$x}[1,42]
```

it produces an array slice, a list of the specified elements in the array to which `$x` is a reference.

If followed by `{LIST}`:

```
@{$x}{ 'foo', 'bar' }
```

it produces a hash slice, a list of the values for the specified keys in the hash to which `$x` is a reference.

[References quick reference](http://perlmonks.org/?node=References%20quick%20reference)

Note that the `{}` around `$x` have no relation to `{}` used to construct an anonymous hash, they are delimiters of a block of code.  If what is in them is a simple scalar variable, they can be omited; if they are not omitted, they can contain an arbitrary expression or even multiple statements that at the end return a reference.