# Is this array, hash or scalar?

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl. I know that `$` is a scalar, `@` an array and `%` a hash.
I have seen a code similar to this (I write it by memory):
`$var = {
           key => value,
           anotherkey => anothervalue
}`

What is this?

Comment: See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html), [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl syntax in relation to references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345834/perl-syntax-in-relation-to-references)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That declares a scalar variable `$var` containing a *reference* to an *anonymous* hash.

References (which are kind of like pointers) are always scalar, no matter what they are referencing.

You could also have done this:

```
 %hash = ( key => value, anotherkey => anothervalue ); #parentheses, not curlies!
 $var = \%hash;
```

In which case the hash referenced by `$var` is no longer anonymous, but the result is otherwise the same.

You can extract the individual elements of the referenced hash by *dereferencing* `$var` with `->` before applying the hash subscript `{`...`}` syntax:

```
$var->{key} # == value, same as $hash{key} in second case
```

Or you can retrieve the whole thing (and recover `%hash`) via `%{$var}`.

See more details [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's a reference to a hash.  See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Answer (score 2):

That's an anonymous hash reference being assigned to a scalar.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Answer (score 2):

It's a Reference (Like a pointer, but not really).

It's a scalar that holds a reference to another scalar, an array or a hash.

Perldoc page on the subject: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html